# Need help writing a program that finds the highest and second highest number is a series

Tags: java

The program is designed for the user to enter a series of numbers until the user enters the sentinel which i set to the value of 0. After the user enters the sentinel the program is supposed to print the highest number and the second highest number in that list. The trouble I'm having is where I expect the second highest number to be it prints 0 instead.

Is there a more elegant way of solving this problem by using the ?: operator? Is it possible?

```
import acm.program.*;

public class LargestAndSecondLargest extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {

        int a = 0;
        int b = 0; 

        while (true) {

            int value = readInt(" ?: ");

            if (value == SENTINEL) break;

            if (value > a) {
                a = value;   
            }
            else if (value > b) {
                b = value;
            }
        }

        println("the largest value is " + a);
        println("the second largest number is"  + b);
    }

    private static final int SENTINEL = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sort descending. Pick first. Pick second. (Unless this is homework or there are other restrictions. An ascending sort can also be used and pick the last/second to last which is often easier in Java due to lack of .. "higher features".)

Comment: @pst.. Sorting would not be efficient than the current way OP is using.

Comment: @pst: What sort of "higher features" would make picking the last element any easier than picking the first? Just curious.

Comment: @thedan HoFs in particular - search SO for sorting a list of integers reverse in Java (and then there are arrays vs other collections). In a language like Scala, Python, Ruby, C#, etc, a custom comparator (i.e. lambda) can often be easily specified to sorting.

Comment: @RohitJain There is "efficient" and "efficient use of my time"; in this case, unless it was a long stream - which is a valid counter-case - I wouldn't think twice. I choose the latter *unless* there is a reason to choose the former. I start with Knuth's observation of 97/3 .. but somehow still find myself on SO far too much :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. The second comparison is wrong.
2. When you encounter a new highest number, you need to shift the previous highest number into the second-highest slot. Otherwise the sequence 1, 2, 3 would produce 3 and 1 as the two highest numbers.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you're saying but I don't understand how to do it. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @JessicaM. - if (value > a) { b = a; a = value; } else if (value > b) { b = value; }

Comment: @Tom thanks. It really clarifies a lot of things I was having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

```
else if ( b > value )
```

The above else if condition should be: -

```
else if ( value > b )
```

Else, your `b` will never get changed, if you are entering only `positive` numbers, and hence the `2nd` largest value will be `0`.

Also see 2nd requirement in @NPE's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13483208/1679863) that is necessarily required.

Comment: I just tried that and it works. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to solve this problem using the ?: operator?

Comment: @JessicaM... No, that won't be possible using `?:` operator. It cannot handle the 2nd highest number.

Answer (score 0):

insert the values into an array.  Sort the array then assign the top two values from the array into your output.  if only one value is given depending on requirements set them both to the same value or one to 0.

Comment: This would work, but has unnecessarily high memory and time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution (that you can adapt with your superclass):

```
public class LargeAndSecondLargest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LargeAndSecondLargest().run("1 2 2");
    }

    public void run(String input) {
        final int SENTINEL = 0;
        int currVal;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextInt() && ((currVal = scanner.nextInt()) != SENTINEL)) {
            numbers.add(currVal);
        }
        printFirstAndSecondLargest(numbers);
    }

    private void printFirstAndSecondLargest(List<Integer> numbers) {
        Collections.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());
        System.out.println("the largest value is " + numbers.get(0));
        System.out.println("the second largest number is " + numbers.get(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: How about the following input: `1 2 2`? I'd expect the output to be `2 2`.

Comment: @NPE it's normal, since no duplicates are allowed within `TreeSet`.